# Pace and ember, how do I make it work in all routes without repeating code

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember with the Pace loading feature.

Pace: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

In my code I am repeating this in each route so that the loading bar appears:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.restart();
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.stop();
  }
});

App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.restart();
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.stop();
  }
});
```

is there a way to not repeat the code in each route? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite all your routes by doing the following:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  activatePace: function() {
    return Pace.restart();
  }.on('activate'),
  deactivatePace: function() {
    return Pace.stop();
  }.on('deactivate')
});
```

Also, this does not interfere with existing `activate/deactivate` hooks, so you don't have to call `this._super()`

See documentation on reopening [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend either creating a [Mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) or utilizing Ember's Loading Route.

So in your case, the Mixin would work as follows:

```
App.PaceLoader = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.restart();
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.stop();
  }
});
```

And then just include it in each route you want it to work in:

```
App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.PaceLoader, {
  //the rest of your route code here...
});
```

I haven't used Pace before, but you may be able to just add it to Ember's less obvious Loading route (I don't believe they've documented it...), which is used in each transition:

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.restart();
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.stop();
  }
});
```

If this works, you wouldn't have to include it in any other routes. :)

Comment: thanks, the last option didn't seem to work but the first option seems interesting although I fixed the issue with @Kalman-Hazins answer which seems easier. Thanks!